# python switch code always matches even when it should not do so

Tags: python

I am trying to replace a largish if-elif block in python with something a bit more like java switch.  My understanding is this should be a bit faster and we are parsing lots of data so if I can get speed improvement I will take it.  However, what is happening is the code is always acting as if the key is 'deposits' even for entries that are not.  The "func =" line is there to validate I am getting things correctly.  I will probably not return a result to func since my goal is to fill a list with results.
What am I doing wrong that the switcher.get always finds a match even when one does not exist?

```
`def parsePollFile(thisFile):
    line = ''
    switcher = {
        'deposits': deposits(line)
    }
    try:
        reader = csv.reader(open(thisFile, 'r'))
        for line in reader:
            try:
                if line[2] == "D":
                    func = switcher.get(line[0], lambda: 'invalid key')
                    print('key: {} -- {}\n'.format(line[0],func))
            except IndexError:
                continue
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception {}\n".format(e))
`
```

Comment: Can you try to reduce this to a [mcve] so we don't have to guess what your input data looks like or how you are calling this function?

Comment: `'deposits' : deposits`, that is, don't call the function when you declare the dictionary.   Then, call `func(line)` instead of `func`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the code

```
switcher = {'deposits': deposits(line)}
```

Doesn't create a key in your dictionary with the value being the `deposits` function object. `'deposits': deposits(line)` actually runs the `deposits` function, and stores the return value as the value of the `'deposits'` key. You need to store a function object in the dictionary.

Since your function takes arguments, this is a bit tricky. There are several ways around this problem, but perhaps the simplest is to wrap your function call in another function

```
switcher = {'deposits': lambda: deposits(line)}
```

You would then use the dictionary like so

```
func = switcher.get(line[0], lambda: 'invalid key')
func()
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution resulted from both the comment and the answer.  I changed the 'deposits': deposits(line) to be 'deposits':deposits and then I run the func(line) when a match is found.

Thank you to the answers.  I did not realize I was actually running the method instead of defining the value.